# Why Questions Appropriate?

Tags: discussion

The OP [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119396/streaming-api-vf-cometd-why-is-task-supported-and-not-event?noredirect=1#comment178406_119396) took exception to our closing of his question as opinion based. However, *why* questions are notoriously difficult to answer, and unless someone on SFSE was on the back-end team that built out the functionality in question, it is basically impossible to answer with anything but opinion.

Should the question be reopened? I do not believe there is any possible answer besides reiterating that it cannot be accomplished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one looks borderline to me, because it is a question that'd have a specific answer, it's just not likely that anyone as that information available and so would lead to opinion-based answers instead.

OP suggested an edit in a comment in response to you, I've asked them to actually edit the question and nominate for re-opening.

One of the drawbacks of the community moderation on SE is that it can appear brutal and cause offence where none is intended, generally if you're voting to close something you should at least leave a comment explaining why. I know you did comment in this instance, but you didn't provide the real why until later.